# Gap size after placing JSeparator in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, grouplayout

I have a simple problem here in Java Swing. I simplified my code to the following snippet. I am not sure how I can minimize the gap size between the horizontal JSeparator with the next JTextField, as current code generates a huge gap between the two.

```
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(jPanel1);          
        jPanel1.setLayout(layout);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(button)
                      ))
                  .addComponent(jSeparator)
                  .addComponent(jTextField)
            );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(button)
                .addComponent(jSeparator)
                .addComponent(jTextField)
            );
```

And also in general, how can I control the gap size to any integer represented value, instead of using the `addPreferredGap`?

Thank you.

Okay, this is the window generated from the code posted above:
[image]

You can see the space between the JSeparator and JTextField is very wide.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing this from a snippet; `GroupLayout` is not known for readability. Some context, a screenshot and [sscce](http://sscce.org/) might be helpful.

Comment: This is the pitfall of using an IDE, such as NetBeans.

Comment: @Moonbeam: I am not using an IDE.

Comment: @Qiang Li, Then why are you using `GroupLayout`?! Ew! :)

Comment: @Moobeam: I thought it is most powerful and flexible layout manager.

Comment: @Qiang Li, That's subjective and I doubt anyone would agree.

Answer (score 3):

Absent your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), the problem appears to be in the code you don't show. The parent container's layout or `pack()` may be involved. Note that the default layout of `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`; the default position is `CENTER`. Here's an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) with which to compare your code.

Addendum: Commenting that the parent of your `GroupLayout` panel is another `JPanel`, you asked the following,

> Do you know how to make this work in my situation?

Yes, give the enclosing `JPanel` a suitable layout, e.g. `GridLayout` as shown below. The latter behaves much like the `BorderLayout.CENTER` of the `JFrame` in this regard.

[image: GroupPanel]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769722 */
public class GroupPanel extends JPanel {

    private final JButton button = new JButton("Start");
    private final JSeparator jSeparator = new JSeparator();
    private final JTextField jTextField = new JTextField(10);

    public GroupPanel() {
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);          
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
            .addComponent(button)
            .addComponent(jSeparator)
            .addComponent(jTextField)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(button, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(jSeparator, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(jTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
    }

    private static void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("GroupPanel");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        f.add(new GroupPanel());
        f.add(new GroupPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I actually did something different from you. I used a JPanel inside the JFrame, while everything else are inside the JPanel. In other words, I set the GroupLayout for JPanel1, as you can see from my code. Do you know how to make this work in my situation?

Comment: Your case is not really different: the enclosing container needs a suitable layout, as shown above.

Comment: aha, I see! Your code is also not working! At least not as I wanted it to be. If you resize the window, you see almost the same effect as in my attached screenshot: there is a big gap between the horizontal separator with the TextField.

Comment: I'd use the default `FlowLayout` or `BoxLayout` with the desired [filler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler).

Comment: do you mind to modify your code above to make it work? My original question persists and I am not sure how I can solve it. Many thanks.

Comment: To see the default `FlowLayout`, simply delete `new GridLayout()`; `BoxLayout` is left as an exercise for the reader. As you are using the GUI editor, experiment with different layouts and examine the generated code.

Comment: See also [Component Size and Resizability](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html).

Comment: did you try resize your window using the code you gave above? It will generate the same window as I posed. :(

Comment: Yes. I sense you didn't do the steps required [to make a component fixed size](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html).

Answer (score 2):

in the vertical layout, add the separator in the following way:

```
addComponent(separator, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
             GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
```